# svg logo formatting changes whenever I place it on bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4

Whenever I place my svg logo on the navbar, half of it is formatted correctly and the other half is not. Also, it looks different on Safari and Chrome. I exported the svg file from Adobe Illustrator. I am not sure what is going wrong (I am using bootstrap).

[How my logo is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOwRj.png)

[How my logo looks on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltWrh.png)

[How my logo looks on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14icP.png)

Here is the svg:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 7601.82 2387.31" style="enable-background:new 0 0 7601.82 2387.31;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#00ADEE;}
     .st1{fill:none;}
     .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
     .st3{fill:#231F20;}
     .st4{font-family:'AlternateGotNo1D';}
     .st5{font-size:1043.9034px;}
     .st6{letter-spacing:-10.31;}
     .st7{letter-spacing:-4.69;}
     .st8{letter-spacing:-25.32;}
    </style>
    <g>
     <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M1417.48,1732v8.27l11.2,6.47C1424.62,1742.25,1420.84,1737.39,1417.48,1732z"/>
      <path d="M1479.22,1775.91l-50.53-29.17C1442.49,1762,1460.07,1771.83,1479.22,1775.91z"/>
      <path class="st1" d="M3370.67,883.62l-0.01,4.61C3370.78,886.6,3370.77,885.1,3370.67,883.62z"/>
      <path d="M3153.15,1934.24c0,0-0.04-0.02-0.06-0.03l-29.74,3.35C3133.28,1936.45,3143.22,1935.34,3153.15,1934.24z"/>
      <circle cx="1505.03" cy="1681.26" r="101.34"/>
      <g>
       <path class="st0" d="M1706.02,624.76c-2.48,13.9,0.39,21.68,10.17,29.83c30.97,25.82,61.33,52.37,92.71,77.67
        c4.64,3.74,14.49,4.89,20.26,2.74c39.44-14.67,75.45-10.16,104.83,20.43c29.36,30.57,36.82,66.64,20.14,107.15
        c-2.47,5.99-0.21,16.91,4.04,22.22c35.82,44.79,72.41,88.97,109.39,132.81c3.67,4.35,11.86,8.1,17.22,7.3
        c53.28-8,92.73,9.14,114.49,63.66c8.13-6.03,15.1-10.36,21.06-15.78c16.62-15.13,32.3-31.34,49.34-45.96
        c22.63-19.42,35.55-36.97,28.88-72.8c-13.27-71.25,75.13-130.5,144.36-99.9c15.23,6.73,24.94,5.4,37.29-3.87
        c36.54-27.44,74.1-53.53,110.34-81.36c5.51-4.23,9.54-15.42,8.42-22.45c-7.39-46.21,10.73-85.29,51.51-107.11
        c40.45-21.65,92.49-16.51,123,14.55c11,11.19,19.95,15.1,33.97,7.91c6.09-3.12,13.18-4.56,19.98-5.96
        c29.02-5.95,48.42-17.66,57.77-50.89c12.25-43.49,57.45-66.14,105.51-62.78c38.94,2.73,75.28,35.38,84.4,78.27
        c3.03,14.23,9.77,21.02,22.89,25.37c26.38,8.75,48.81,11.59,74.23-8.84c36.88-29.64,77.18-27.64,114.18-2.81
        c34.18,22.93,47.15,60.61,38.51,106.24c-1.35,7.12,2.44,18.02,7.75,23.09c12.28,11.73,25.41,22.55,38.17,33.79l0.3-182.73
        L2395.7,49.23l-806.43,463.81c9.37-2.74,19.1-4.47,29.86-3.4C1676.6,515.37,1716.31,566.96,1706.02,624.76z"/>
       <path class="st2" d="M2180.19,1155.84l-20.52-51.47c-16.09-40.29-39.04-41.76-68.57-37.29l-7.95,0.58
        c-17.74-0.03-36.65-8.89-48.19-22.55c-41.64-49.39-77.65-93.11-110.09-133.68c-12.12-15.13-19.53-42.36-10.18-65.08
        c10-24.26,6.57-42.61-11.46-61.38c-16.49-17.18-33.93-19.4-59.2-10.02c-6.76,2.51-14.11,3.77-21.88,3.75l0,0
        c-8.83-0.01-25.74-1.75-40-13.25c-20-16.1-39.57-32.72-59.14-49.34c-11.35-9.62-22.69-19.26-34.12-28.79
        c-21.87-18.24-29.99-41.16-24.84-70.06c2.84-15.96-0.7-31.49-9.95-43.73c-9.28-12.26-23.2-19.88-39.21-21.48
        c-5.4,0-8.97,0.54-13.63,1.91l-343.83,100.74L2395.78,0l1018.01,590l-0.5,301.47l-82.14-72.17c-9.47-8.18-18.93-16.35-27.97-25
        c-15.92-15.22-24.22-40.68-20.17-61.9c8.26-43.62-13.3-58.08-20.38-62.83c-23.47-15.76-43.01-16.03-63.73,0.63
        c-20.58,16.55-43.3,24.92-67.49,24.88c-18.08-0.03-34.54-4.72-46.85-8.79c-27.91-9.26-45.13-28.44-51.17-57.03
        c-5.01-23.52-25.08-43.12-45.68-44.56c-23.6-1.57-54.18,5.79-61.49,31.8c-16.75,59.54-59.52,74.79-90.23,81.08
        c-3.23,0.67-6.48,1.04-9.34,2.26c-10.58,5.42-21.53,8.22-32.28,8.2c-27.47-0.05-45.41-18.28-51.3-24.29
        c-16.11-16.4-48.78-19.51-72.49-6.84c-24.18,12.94-34.11,34.06-29.51,62.78c3.64,22.74-6.67,49.23-24.52,62.97
        c-20.8,15.97-41.98,31.35-63.16,46.72c-15.92,11.56-31.86,23.12-47.61,34.95c-25.01,18.82-50.57,21.83-80.11,8.78
        c-23.98-10.63-57.69-1.04-75.2,20.01c-6.04,7.25-12.67,18.87-10.02,33.08c10.76,57.75-15.71,89.5-43.02,112.96
        c-9.53,8.19-18.58,16.89-27.65,25.57c-6.87,6.59-13.75,13.18-20.78,19.58c-5.23,4.77-10.99,8.98-17.48,13.56L2180.19,1155.84z
         M2108.59,980.42c41.79,0.07,76.04,14.99,101.24,43.69c0.31-0.3,0.63-0.61,0.95-0.91c10.2-9.78,20.42-19.55,31.12-28.73
        c16.71-14.35,17.49-17.78,14.72-32.63c-6.8-36.48,3.26-73.15,28.3-103.25c40.91-49.16,114.57-68.8,172.5-44.61
        c15.91-11.84,30.89-22.71,45.87-33.58c17.45-12.68,34.92-25.35,52.14-38.36c-5.65-59.99,21.81-111.87,74.9-140.29
        c22.35-11.97,47.69-18.27,73.27-18.23c36.61,0.06,70.19,12.68,95.31,35.69c7.33-2.54,14.18-3.96,19.67-5.09
        c19.02-3.91,21.8-7.4,25.56-20.73c17.1-60.72,77.43-98.8,149.53-93.75c56.85,3.98,107.41,48.66,122,107.04
        c5.52,1.69,11.38,3.13,15.89,3.14c2.39,0,6.37,0.01,13.94-6.07c21.22-17.06,45.03-27.41,69.55-30.36L2395.61,98.45l-695.98,400.3
        c8.34,6.84,15.89,14.67,22.47,23.35c22.57,29.85,32,66.67,26.81,104.26c9.94,8.34,19.61,16.55,29.27,24.75
        c15.83,13.43,31.65,26.87,47.7,40.02c52.89-15.91,102.23-3.34,138.85,34.77c38.34,39.92,49.95,89.42,33.35,140.53
        c28.24,35.17,59.27,72.84,94.43,114.65C2098.01,980.64,2103.39,980.41,2108.59,980.42z"/>
      </g>
      <g>
       <path class="st0" d="M3063.12,1864.07c-27.07-1.32-54.2-2.6-81.25-1.92c-6.29,0.16-15.01,6.67-18.14,12.61
        c-20.32,38.52-59.52,58.04-105.27,50.91c-51.45-8.01-74.96-28.37-80.77-77.46c-3.14-26.49-13.18-43.71-37-54.98
        c-25.06-11.87-49.24-25.61-73.95-38.62c-31.51,27.58-66.5,34.29-103.88,16.98c-35.18-16.29-58.43-43.16-61.91-83.45
        c-0.78-9.08-1.56-20.12,2.67-27.31c11.52-19.56,1.56-30.46-11.38-43.35c-30.19-30.08-59.8-60.79-88.33-92.45
        c-10.04-11.14-19.15-12.51-32.47-8.62c-37.35,10.92-69.2,0.17-93.94-28.93c-26.17-30.77-32.96-65.28-16.57-103.79
        c2.85-6.69,1.79-18.32-2.38-24.16c-20.63-28.93-42.9-56.68-66.47-87.28c-21.53,45.06-56.75,67.3-104.66,68.86
        c-7.64,0.25-16.56,1.06-22.8-2.29c-22.96-12.31-38.13-1.66-54.53,13.5c-38.15,35.25-77.36,69.37-116.54,103.49
        c-9.67,8.42-13.72,16.47-10.47,29.95c9.96,41.31,0.27,77.3-34.97,103.16c-38.78,28.46-79.81,29.32-122.51,7.73
        c-6.74-3.41-18.23-3.87-24.64-0.39c-31.28,16.98-61.92,35.23-91.91,54.4c-5.28,3.38-9.19,13.44-8.92,20.21
        c2.01,50.1-20.79,84.1-68.85,100.35c-17.94,6.07-36.09,6.82-53.06,3.18l913.74,529.57l704.75-405.33
        c-7.26-8.1-13.75-17.11-18.28-28.52C3077.02,1866.58,3068.48,1864.33,3063.12,1864.07z"/>
       <path class="st2" d="M2391.88,2353.24l-1168.42-677.17l263.72,56.69c10.03,2.17,20.44,1.52,30.44-1.88
        c29.61-10.01,41.18-26.9,39.93-58.27c-0.77-18.54,7.83-44.58,28.53-57.83c31.73-20.31,63.55-39.13,94.55-55.97
        c9.11-4.95,20.14-7.57,31.82-7.55c8.16,0.01,20.4,1.3,32.41,7.38c29.58,14.95,53.27,14.08,78.05-4.08
        c13.83-10.15,26.87-25.08,18.74-58.79c-6.77-28.16,1.28-52.4,23.92-72.11c38.28-33.31,77.85-67.77,115.61-102.63
        c10.62-9.82,32.73-30.26,64.46-30.2c11.35,0.02,22.77,2.66,34,7.87l6.47-0.17c32.87-1.08,53.08-14.43,67.51-44.63l29.91-62.6
        l60.67,78.63c17.17,22.05,33.57,43.15,49.06,64.88c12.61,17.7,15.52,45.28,6.91,65.56c-9.56,22.43-6.62,40.21,9.8,59.51
        c13.77,16.19,25.83,18.08,33.7,18.1c4.84,0.01,10.16-0.83,15.78-2.47c31.19-9.09,55.82-1.53,76.13,21.01
        c25.84,28.67,54.21,58.37,86.74,90.77c11.17,11.14,44.48,44.29,20.57,90.56c0.02,2.25,0.34,4.55,0.52,6.66
        c1.31,15.07,6.73,34.24,37.35,48.4c21.3,9.86,38.31,6.78,57.89-10.38l22.03-19.27l48.78,25.87c16.38,8.83,32.7,17.65,49.46,25.58
        c36.08,17.07,56.06,46.03,61.09,88.51c2.97,25.15,7.37,34.49,45,40.35c26.92,4.14,48.99-5.93,61-28.7
        c9.01-17.07,30.69-34.69,54.7-35.34c28.52-0.65,56.36,0.59,84.49,1.96c19.57,0.95,43.74,10.08,52.84,32.87
        c2.13,5.36,5.23,10.08,10.4,15.84l35.16,39.2L2391.88,2353.24z M1588.99,1789.36l803.06,465.43l496.31-285.47
        c-11.69,0.95-23.91,0.46-36.47-1.5c-45.05-7.03-106.14-26.54-116.54-114.58c-1.85-15.57-5.48-17.94-12.89-21.45
        c-17.72-8.38-35.01-17.66-52.33-27c-38.66,23.07-82.66,25.19-125.19,5.51c-51.94-24.04-81.83-65-86.46-118.47
        c-0.91-10.62-2.33-27.25,4.08-43.72c-0.12-0.13-0.26-0.26-0.4-0.4c-31.65-31.53-59.55-60.64-85.12-88.81
        c-49.93,13.13-97.55-3.21-132.01-43.77c-35.43-41.68-44.67-89.49-26.96-138.82c-8.1-11.14-16.46-22.15-25.05-33.28
        c-27.27,25.48-62.48,39.37-104.18,40.73c-5.09,0.2-7.84,0.29-10.56,0.29c-8.02-0.01-19.89-0.74-31.92-6.67
        c-1.6,1.22-3.92,3.17-7.3,6.3c-37.13,34.27-75.49,67.76-112.75,100.2c11.06,56.89-7.56,106.14-52.94,139.45
        c-48.19,35.37-103.85,40.6-159.99,14.81c-23.18,12.79-46.81,26.75-70.49,41.62C1642.13,1726.74,1623.46,1764.31,1588.99,1789.36z
        "/>
      </g>
      <g>
       <path d="M1515.02,617.32C1520.22,619.47,1513.81,612.05,1515.02,617.32c6.88,29.97,20.81,54.28,47.1,71.86
        c5.75,3.84,9.45,15.9,8.65,23.62c-20.92,203.02-42.59,405.97-64.04,608.94c-8.05,76.13-16.36,152.24-23.44,228.47
        c-1.76,18.97-5.68,31.04-26.2,39.37c-15.91,6.46-31.39,21.05-40.34,36.2l-0.17,104.65c3.34,5.39,7.12,10.26,11.18,14.76
        l50.48,29.26c16.98,3.64,35.13,2.89,53.06-3.18c48.06-16.26,70.86-50.26,68.85-100.35c-0.27-6.78,3.64-16.84,8.92-20.21
        c29.99-19.18,60.63-37.42,91.91-54.4c6.41-3.48,17.9-3.02,24.64,0.39c42.7,21.59,83.74,20.72,122.51-7.73
        c35.24-25.86,44.93-61.86,34.97-103.16c-3.25-13.48,0.8-21.53,10.47-29.95c39.18-34.11,78.39-68.24,116.54-103.49
        c16.41-15.16,31.57-25.81,54.53-13.5c6.24,3.34,15.16,2.54,22.8,2.29c47.91-1.56,83.13-23.8,104.66-68.86
        c23.56,30.59,45.84,58.35,66.47,87.28c4.17,5.84,5.22,17.47,2.38,24.16c-16.39,38.51-9.6,73.02,16.57,103.79
        c24.74,29.1,56.59,39.85,93.94,28.93c13.32-3.9,22.43-2.53,32.47,8.62c28.52,31.65,58.14,62.37,88.33,92.45
        c12.93,12.89,22.9,23.79,11.38,43.35c-4.23,7.19-3.45,18.23-2.67,27.31c3.48,40.29,26.73,67.16,61.91,83.45
        c37.38,17.31,72.37,10.6,103.88-16.98c24.71,13,48.89,26.75,73.95,38.62c23.82,11.28,33.86,28.49,37,54.98
        c5.81,49.08,29.32,69.44,80.77,77.46c45.76,7.13,84.95-12.4,105.27-50.91c3.13-5.95,11.85-12.45,18.14-12.61
        c27.06-0.69,54.19,0.6,81.25,1.92c5.36,0.26,13.9,2.5,15.32,6.08c4.53,11.41,11.02,20.43,18.28,28.52l272.53-156.75l0.06-36.61
        c-35.19,16.39-70.23,33.11-105.4,49.56c-17.73,8.29-50.19-10.89-51.54-31.44c2.97-62.93,6.01-127.1,9.02-191.28
        c5.33-113.69,10.63-227.37,15.97-341.06c5.78-122.95,11.46-245.9,17.51-368.83c0.98-19.85,15.11-28.26,31.14-16.12
        c28.96,21.92,55.88,46.61,82.67,71.21c1.33,1.22,1.8,3.59,1.98,6.25l0.14-86.35c-12.75-11.24-25.89-22.06-38.17-33.79
        c-5.31-5.07-9.09-15.98-7.75-23.09c8.64-45.63-4.33-83.31-38.51-106.24c-37.01-24.83-77.3-26.83-114.18,2.81
        c-25.43,20.43-47.85,17.59-74.23,8.84c-13.12-4.35-19.86-11.14-22.89-25.37c-9.12-42.89-45.46-75.54-84.4-78.27
        c-48.06-3.36-93.26,19.29-105.51,62.78c-9.36,33.23-28.75,44.93-57.77,50.89c-6.8,1.4-13.89,2.84-19.98,5.96
        c-14.02,7.18-22.97,3.28-33.97-7.91c-30.51-31.06-82.55-36.2-123-14.55c-40.77,21.82-58.9,60.9-51.51,107.11
        c1.12,7.03-2.91,18.22-8.42,22.45c-36.24,27.82-73.8,53.91-110.34,81.36c-12.35,9.27-22.07,10.6-37.29,3.87
        c-69.23-30.6-157.63,28.66-144.36,99.9c6.67,35.83-6.25,53.38-28.88,72.8c-17.04,14.62-32.71,30.84-49.34,45.96
        c-5.96,5.43-12.93,9.75-21.06,15.78c-21.76-54.52-61.21-71.66-114.49-63.66c-5.36,0.8-13.55-2.95-17.22-7.3
        c-36.98-43.84-73.57-88.02-109.39-132.81c-4.24-5.31-6.5-16.22-4.04-22.22c16.69-40.51,9.22-76.58-20.14-107.15
        c-29.38-30.59-65.39-35.1-104.83-20.43c-5.77,2.14-15.62,1-20.26-2.74c-31.38-25.3-61.74-51.86-92.71-77.67
        c-9.78-8.15-12.65-15.93-10.17-29.83c10.29-57.8-29.42-109.39-86.89-115.11c-10.75-1.07-20.49,0.66-29.86,3.4 M1779.41,1291.33
        c-4.13,33.02-6.63,66.27-11.99,99.07c-1.4,8.58-9.08,20.05-16.69,23.06c-47.11,18.63-68.76,53.4-67.93,102.56
        c0.23,13.76-4.37,20.67-15.75,27.07c-29.66,16.66-58.48,34.81-87.9,51.9c-15.5,9-36.21-2.66-36.38-17.67
        c6.9-71.5,13.25-140.83,20.34-210.08c21.2-206.98,42.71-413.92,64.05-620.88c1.03-9.98,1.32-20.04,2.41-30.02
        c2.4-22.1,26.17-32.7,43.65-18.68c33.27,26.67,66.09,53.92,98.38,81.76c3.78,3.26,5.18,12.16,4.08,17.74
        c-8.68,44.25,6.47,78.45,40.6,106.68c5.97,4.94,9.27,17.45,8.27,25.81C1810.04,1050.26,1794.49,1170.76,1779.41,1291.33z
         M2022.39,1079.74c-5.65,19.23-2.95,40.81-4.74,61.3c-0.87,10.01-0.91,21.93-6.31,29.38c-21.67,29.94-32.32,60.97-21.25,98.03
        c1.9,6.37-1.68,17.7-6.75,22.31c-47.61,43.17-96.09,85.39-144.41,127.77c-0.85,0.75-2.96,0.07-12.29-0.02
        c17.57-169.82,39.84-337.62,63.28-510.26c10.51,6.56,18.81,9.36,23.58,15.1c34.67,41.67,68.44,84.08,102.96,125.88
        C2024.43,1058.86,2026.4,1066.1,2022.39,1079.74z M2351.26,1113.5c-6.53,63.75-13.12,127.5-19.81,191.23
        c-0.64,6.1-1.44,12.35-3.4,18.11c-4.44,13.07-11.28,16.42-20.83,3.81c-35.44-46.8-70.93-93.57-109.47-144.41
        c52.22-48.8,103.22-96.46,154.22-144.12c2.11,1.08,4.21,2.16,6.32,3.23C2355.95,1065.4,2353.72,1089.46,2351.26,1113.5z
         M2579.48,1564.84c-1.01,9.27-5.94,19.24-12.05,26.27c-2.3,2.65-15.49,0.27-19.73-3.88c-36.52-35.8-72.3-72.36-107.71-109.26
        c-3.21-3.34-4.43-11.19-3.06-15.95c14-48.79,0.31-87.86-38.77-119.6c-5.2-4.22-8.85-14.38-8.12-21.25
        c9.09-86.14,18.74-172.22,29.6-258.15c0.9-7.14,10.41-15.8,17.95-19.05c37.62-16.19,63.46-41.33,67.58-83.72
        c1.01-10.35-2.03-21.09-3.21-31.65c-1.34-0.48-2.67-0.95-4.01-1.42c3.9-6.96,6.14-16.12,11.97-20.52
        c41.38-31.26,83.38-61.69,125.6-91.8c2.99-2.13,11.78-1.31,13.64,1.23c3.93,5.37,7.5,13.01,6.95,19.35
        c-4.26,49.29-9.34,98.51-14.54,147.7C2621.08,1177.06,2600.56,1370.98,2579.48,1564.84z M2872.97,1471.1
        c-6.71,78.41-11.7,156.96-18.53,235.35c-0.96,10.99-5.83,28.79-12.61,30.79c-21.56,6.34-40.22,35.84-68.45,8.31
        c-14.24-13.9-36.59-19.45-55.2-28.91c-14.46-7.35-27.52-15.73-22.02-34.24c-2.57-33.39-17.02-59.29-42.58-78.03
        c-11.73-8.6-14.31-17.01-12.76-31.2c26.02-239.04,51.42-478.15,76.62-717.28c1.78-16.9,4.83-28.8,24.05-36.09
        c33.2-12.6,53.24-39.53,60.32-74.43c2.63-12.98,7.11-20.73,20.91-23.06c9.81-1.66,19.83-4.77,28.59-9.43
        c31.82-16.94,56.31-4.52,77.23,19.15c4.76,5.39,6.85,15.42,6.21,22.97C2914.42,993.72,2893.4,1232.39,2872.97,1471.1z
         M3177.72,1131.36c-4.53,93.53-8.89,187.07-13.6,280.6c-5.02,99.68-10.47,199.33-15.47,299.01
        c-0.67,13.26-6.43,20.76-17.29,29.25c-19.03,14.86-34.29,34.48-51.78,51.43c-4.65,4.51-11.42,8.7-17.61,9.37
        c-13.01,1.4-26.5-1.13-39.42,0.64c-31.02,4.23-59.87,5.6-72.96-31.34c-0.95-2.68-3.65-5.78-6.24-6.69
        c-36.35-12.79-30.1-40.55-27.49-69.84c27.67-311.26,54.38-622.61,81.39-933.93c0.4-4.61-0.43-11.43,2.18-13.39
        c19.62-14.74,39.02-30.31,60.57-41.68c8.33-4.4,22.15,0.77,33.29,2.68c21.82,3.76,36.07,11.33,43.46,37.65
        c5.95,21.2,29.3,37.57,45.1,55.94c4.42,5.13,9.46,9.72,11.33,11.63C3187.85,922.66,3182.78,1027.01,3177.72,1131.36z"/>
      </g>
      <g>
       <circle cx="1608.14" cy="606.81" r="97.49"/>
      </g>
      <g>
       <circle cx="1501.18" cy="1681.26" r="110.19"/>
      </g>
      <g>
       <circle cx="3172.09" cy="1834.67" r="101.34"/>
      </g>
      <circle cx="3407.08" cy="1707.72" r="101.34"/>
      <circle cx="3408.44" cy="888.29" r="101.34"/>
     </g>
     <text transform="matrix(1.0665 0 0 1 3229.4033 1631.7931)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st3 st4 st5"> </tspan><tspan x="180.95" y="0" class="st3 st4 st5 st6">B</tspan><tspan x="536.49" y="0" class="st3 st4 st5 st7">I</tspan><tspan x="712.22" y="0" class="st3 st4 st5 st8">OTECH GRO</tspan><tspan x="3408.73" y="0" class="st3 st4 st5 st6">UP</tspan></text>
     <path class="st3" d="M424.08,546.76h196.26v1168.82H480.15V890.21l-136.69,825.36h-70.09L136.69,890.21v825.36H0V546.76h192.76
      l115.66,581.78L424.08,546.76z"/>
     <path class="st3" d="M909.2,1715.58H746.23V546.76H909.2V1715.58z"/>
     <path class="st3" d="M1126.61,699.21H974.15V546.76h474.89v152.45h-159.47v1016.37h-162.97V699.21z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<!--<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">-->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/MBGlogo.svg" width="250" height="30" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Get Involved</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Career Fair</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ideation</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Jobs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sponsorship</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This question is related to SVG, so where is the SVG?

Comment: Just attached it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your SVG uses plain `<text>` elements. For it to display properly, the "AlternateGotNo1D" font needs to either be installed on the end users computer; or it needs to be embedded in your SVG as a file URL.

The simplest solution by far is to convert the text to outlines.  That way the display of the text is guaranteed to be consistent across browsers.

- Open the file in Illustrator
- Select the text
- Do Type -> Create outlines
- Export as SVG again.

If you do this (convert to outlines) and you are still having display issues, double check that you SVG no longer has any `<text>` elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your svg. Since you are using the x and y attributes for the `tspan` elements the text will appear jammed outside Illustrator if you are using a different font. The solution is removing the x and y attributes for the `tspan` elements.

Also I had to change the `viewBox` value since the text was falling outside the svg canvas. If you are using a different font in your project you may need to recalculate the value for the `viewBox` attribute. In order to do it you may need to use a little javascript to get the size and position of the wrapper group: `wrapper.getBBox()`

The returned value of `wrapper.getBBox()` is a SVGRect object, which defines the bounding box of the wrapper (x,y,width,height).
The value of the viewBox attribute should be `bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height` where bb iss the bounding box object.

I hope it helps.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 13000 2387.31" style="enable-background:new 0 0 7601.82 2387.31;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#00ADEE;}
    .st1{fill:none;}
    .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st3{fill:#231F20;}
    .st4{font-family:'AlternateGotNo1D';}
    .st5{font-size:1043.9034px;}
    .st6{letter-spacing:-10.31;}
    .st7{letter-spacing:-4.69;}
    .st8{letter-spacing:-25.32;}
</style>
<g id="wrapper">
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M1417.48,1732v8.27l11.2,6.47C1424.62,1742.25,1420.84,1737.39,1417.48,1732z"/>
        <path d="M1479.22,1775.91l-50.53-29.17C1442.49,1762,1460.07,1771.83,1479.22,1775.91z"/>
        <path class="st1" d="M3370.67,883.62l-0.01,4.61C3370.78,886.6,3370.77,885.1,3370.67,883.62z"/>
        <path d="M3153.15,1934.24c0,0-0.04-0.02-0.06-0.03l-29.74,3.35C3133.28,1936.45,3143.22,1935.34,3153.15,1934.24z"/>
        <circle cx="1505.03" cy="1681.26" r="101.34"/>
        <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M1706.02,624.76c-2.48,13.9,0.39,21.68,10.17,29.83c30.97,25.82,61.33,52.37,92.71,77.67
                c4.64,3.74,14.49,4.89,20.26,2.74c39.44-14.67,75.45-10.16,104.83,20.43c29.36,30.57,36.82,66.64,20.14,107.15
                c-2.47,5.99-0.21,16.91,4.04,22.22c35.82,44.79,72.41,88.97,109.39,132.81c3.67,4.35,11.86,8.1,17.22,7.3
                c53.28-8,92.73,9.14,114.49,63.66c8.13-6.03,15.1-10.36,21.06-15.78c16.62-15.13,32.3-31.34,49.34-45.96
                c22.63-19.42,35.55-36.97,28.88-72.8c-13.27-71.25,75.13-130.5,144.36-99.9c15.23,6.73,24.94,5.4,37.29-3.87
                c36.54-27.44,74.1-53.53,110.34-81.36c5.51-4.23,9.54-15.42,8.42-22.45c-7.39-46.21,10.73-85.29,51.51-107.11
                c40.45-21.65,92.49-16.51,123,14.55c11,11.19,19.95,15.1,33.97,7.91c6.09-3.12,13.18-4.56,19.98-5.96
                c29.02-5.95,48.42-17.66,57.77-50.89c12.25-43.49,57.45-66.14,105.51-62.78c38.94,2.73,75.28,35.38,84.4,78.27
                c3.03,14.23,9.77,21.02,22.89,25.37c26.38,8.75,48.81,11.59,74.23-8.84c36.88-29.64,77.18-27.64,114.18-2.81
                c34.18,22.93,47.15,60.61,38.51,106.24c-1.35,7.12,2.44,18.02,7.75,23.09c12.28,11.73,25.41,22.55,38.17,33.79l0.3-182.73
                L2395.7,49.23l-806.43,463.81c9.37-2.74,19.1-4.47,29.86-3.4C1676.6,515.37,1716.31,566.96,1706.02,624.76z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M2180.19,1155.84l-20.52-51.47c-16.09-40.29-39.04-41.76-68.57-37.29l-7.95,0.58
                c-17.74-0.03-36.65-8.89-48.19-22.55c-41.64-49.39-77.65-93.11-110.09-133.68c-12.12-15.13-19.53-42.36-10.18-65.08
                c10-24.26,6.57-42.61-11.46-61.38c-16.49-17.18-33.93-19.4-59.2-10.02c-6.76,2.51-14.11,3.77-21.88,3.75l0,0
                c-8.83-0.01-25.74-1.75-40-13.25c-20-16.1-39.57-32.72-59.14-49.34c-11.35-9.62-22.69-19.26-34.12-28.79
                c-21.87-18.24-29.99-41.16-24.84-70.06c2.84-15.96-0.7-31.49-9.95-43.73c-9.28-12.26-23.2-19.88-39.21-21.48
                c-5.4,0-8.97,0.54-13.63,1.91l-343.83,100.74L2395.78,0l1018.01,590l-0.5,301.47l-82.14-72.17c-9.47-8.18-18.93-16.35-27.97-25
                c-15.92-15.22-24.22-40.68-20.17-61.9c8.26-43.62-13.3-58.08-20.38-62.83c-23.47-15.76-43.01-16.03-63.73,0.63
                c-20.58,16.55-43.3,24.92-67.49,24.88c-18.08-0.03-34.54-4.72-46.85-8.79c-27.91-9.26-45.13-28.44-51.17-57.03
                c-5.01-23.52-25.08-43.12-45.68-44.56c-23.6-1.57-54.18,5.79-61.49,31.8c-16.75,59.54-59.52,74.79-90.23,81.08
                c-3.23,0.67-6.48,1.04-9.34,2.26c-10.58,5.42-21.53,8.22-32.28,8.2c-27.47-0.05-45.41-18.28-51.3-24.29
                c-16.11-16.4-48.78-19.51-72.49-6.84c-24.18,12.94-34.11,34.06-29.51,62.78c3.64,22.74-6.67,49.23-24.52,62.97
                c-20.8,15.97-41.98,31.35-63.16,46.72c-15.92,11.56-31.86,23.12-47.61,34.95c-25.01,18.82-50.57,21.83-80.11,8.78
                c-23.98-10.63-57.69-1.04-75.2,20.01c-6.04,7.25-12.67,18.87-10.02,33.08c10.76,57.75-15.71,89.5-43.02,112.96
                c-9.53,8.19-18.58,16.89-27.65,25.57c-6.87,6.59-13.75,13.18-20.78,19.58c-5.23,4.77-10.99,8.98-17.48,13.56L2180.19,1155.84z
                 M2108.59,980.42c41.79,0.07,76.04,14.99,101.24,43.69c0.31-0.3,0.63-0.61,0.95-0.91c10.2-9.78,20.42-19.55,31.12-28.73
                c16.71-14.35,17.49-17.78,14.72-32.63c-6.8-36.48,3.26-73.15,28.3-103.25c40.91-49.16,114.57-68.8,172.5-44.61
                c15.91-11.84,30.89-22.71,45.87-33.58c17.45-12.68,34.92-25.35,52.14-38.36c-5.65-59.99,21.81-111.87,74.9-140.29
                c22.35-11.97,47.69-18.27,73.27-18.23c36.61,0.06,70.19,12.68,95.31,35.69c7.33-2.54,14.18-3.96,19.67-5.09
                c19.02-3.91,21.8-7.4,25.56-20.73c17.1-60.72,77.43-98.8,149.53-93.75c56.85,3.98,107.41,48.66,122,107.04
                c5.52,1.69,11.38,3.13,15.89,3.14c2.39,0,6.37,0.01,13.94-6.07c21.22-17.06,45.03-27.41,69.55-30.36L2395.61,98.45l-695.98,400.3
                c8.34,6.84,15.89,14.67,22.47,23.35c22.57,29.85,32,66.67,26.81,104.26c9.94,8.34,19.61,16.55,29.27,24.75
                c15.83,13.43,31.65,26.87,47.7,40.02c52.89-15.91,102.23-3.34,138.85,34.77c38.34,39.92,49.95,89.42,33.35,140.53
                c28.24,35.17,59.27,72.84,94.43,114.65C2098.01,980.64,2103.39,980.41,2108.59,980.42z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M3063.12,1864.07c-27.07-1.32-54.2-2.6-81.25-1.92c-6.29,0.16-15.01,6.67-18.14,12.61
                c-20.32,38.52-59.52,58.04-105.27,50.91c-51.45-8.01-74.96-28.37-80.77-77.46c-3.14-26.49-13.18-43.71-37-54.98
                c-25.06-11.87-49.24-25.61-73.95-38.62c-31.51,27.58-66.5,34.29-103.88,16.98c-35.18-16.29-58.43-43.16-61.91-83.45
                c-0.78-9.08-1.56-20.12,2.67-27.31c11.52-19.56,1.56-30.46-11.38-43.35c-30.19-30.08-59.8-60.79-88.33-92.45
                c-10.04-11.14-19.15-12.51-32.47-8.62c-37.35,10.92-69.2,0.17-93.94-28.93c-26.17-30.77-32.96-65.28-16.57-103.79
                c2.85-6.69,1.79-18.32-2.38-24.16c-20.63-28.93-42.9-56.68-66.47-87.28c-21.53,45.06-56.75,67.3-104.66,68.86
                c-7.64,0.25-16.56,1.06-22.8-2.29c-22.96-12.31-38.13-1.66-54.53,13.5c-38.15,35.25-77.36,69.37-116.54,103.49
                c-9.67,8.42-13.72,16.47-10.47,29.95c9.96,41.31,0.27,77.3-34.97,103.16c-38.78,28.46-79.81,29.32-122.51,7.73
                c-6.74-3.41-18.23-3.87-24.64-0.39c-31.28,16.98-61.92,35.23-91.91,54.4c-5.28,3.38-9.19,13.44-8.92,20.21
                c2.01,50.1-20.79,84.1-68.85,100.35c-17.94,6.07-36.09,6.82-53.06,3.18l913.74,529.57l704.75-405.33
                c-7.26-8.1-13.75-17.11-18.28-28.52C3077.02,1866.58,3068.48,1864.33,3063.12,1864.07z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M2391.88,2353.24l-1168.42-677.17l263.72,56.69c10.03,2.17,20.44,1.52,30.44-1.88
                c29.61-10.01,41.18-26.9,39.93-58.27c-0.77-18.54,7.83-44.58,28.53-57.83c31.73-20.31,63.55-39.13,94.55-55.97
                c9.11-4.95,20.14-7.57,31.82-7.55c8.16,0.01,20.4,1.3,32.41,7.38c29.58,14.95,53.27,14.08,78.05-4.08
                c13.83-10.15,26.87-25.08,18.74-58.79c-6.77-28.16,1.28-52.4,23.92-72.11c38.28-33.31,77.85-67.77,115.61-102.63
                c10.62-9.82,32.73-30.26,64.46-30.2c11.35,0.02,22.77,2.66,34,7.87l6.47-0.17c32.87-1.08,53.08-14.43,67.51-44.63l29.91-62.6
                l60.67,78.63c17.17,22.05,33.57,43.15,49.06,64.88c12.61,17.7,15.52,45.28,6.91,65.56c-9.56,22.43-6.62,40.21,9.8,59.51
                c13.77,16.19,25.83,18.08,33.7,18.1c4.84,0.01,10.16-0.83,15.78-2.47c31.19-9.09,55.82-1.53,76.13,21.01
                c25.84,28.67,54.21,58.37,86.74,90.77c11.17,11.14,44.48,44.29,20.57,90.56c0.02,2.25,0.34,4.55,0.52,6.66
                c1.31,15.07,6.73,34.24,37.35,48.4c21.3,9.86,38.31,6.78,57.89-10.38l22.03-19.27l48.78,25.87c16.38,8.83,32.7,17.65,49.46,25.58
                c36.08,17.07,56.06,46.03,61.09,88.51c2.97,25.15,7.37,34.49,45,40.35c26.92,4.14,48.99-5.93,61-28.7
                c9.01-17.07,30.69-34.69,54.7-35.34c28.52-0.65,56.36,0.59,84.49,1.96c19.57,0.95,43.74,10.08,52.84,32.87
                c2.13,5.36,5.23,10.08,10.4,15.84l35.16,39.2L2391.88,2353.24z M1588.99,1789.36l803.06,465.43l496.31-285.47
                c-11.69,0.95-23.91,0.46-36.47-1.5c-45.05-7.03-106.14-26.54-116.54-114.58c-1.85-15.57-5.48-17.94-12.89-21.45
                c-17.72-8.38-35.01-17.66-52.33-27c-38.66,23.07-82.66,25.19-125.19,5.51c-51.94-24.04-81.83-65-86.46-118.47
                c-0.91-10.62-2.33-27.25,4.08-43.72c-0.12-0.13-0.26-0.26-0.4-0.4c-31.65-31.53-59.55-60.64-85.12-88.81
                c-49.93,13.13-97.55-3.21-132.01-43.77c-35.43-41.68-44.67-89.49-26.96-138.82c-8.1-11.14-16.46-22.15-25.05-33.28
                c-27.27,25.48-62.48,39.37-104.18,40.73c-5.09,0.2-7.84,0.29-10.56,0.29c-8.02-0.01-19.89-0.74-31.92-6.67
                c-1.6,1.22-3.92,3.17-7.3,6.3c-37.13,34.27-75.49,67.76-112.75,100.2c11.06,56.89-7.56,106.14-52.94,139.45
                c-48.19,35.37-103.85,40.6-159.99,14.81c-23.18,12.79-46.81,26.75-70.49,41.62C1642.13,1726.74,1623.46,1764.31,1588.99,1789.36z
                "/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path d="M1515.02,617.32C1520.22,619.47,1513.81,612.05,1515.02,617.32c6.88,29.97,20.81,54.28,47.1,71.86
                c5.75,3.84,9.45,15.9,8.65,23.62c-20.92,203.02-42.59,405.97-64.04,608.94c-8.05,76.13-16.36,152.24-23.44,228.47
                c-1.76,18.97-5.68,31.04-26.2,39.37c-15.91,6.46-31.39,21.05-40.34,36.2l-0.17,104.65c3.34,5.39,7.12,10.26,11.18,14.76
                l50.48,29.26c16.98,3.64,35.13,2.89,53.06-3.18c48.06-16.26,70.86-50.26,68.85-100.35c-0.27-6.78,3.64-16.84,8.92-20.21
                c29.99-19.18,60.63-37.42,91.91-54.4c6.41-3.48,17.9-3.02,24.64,0.39c42.7,21.59,83.74,20.72,122.51-7.73
                c35.24-25.86,44.93-61.86,34.97-103.16c-3.25-13.48,0.8-21.53,10.47-29.95c39.18-34.11,78.39-68.24,116.54-103.49
                c16.41-15.16,31.57-25.81,54.53-13.5c6.24,3.34,15.16,2.54,22.8,2.29c47.91-1.56,83.13-23.8,104.66-68.86
                c23.56,30.59,45.84,58.35,66.47,87.28c4.17,5.84,5.22,17.47,2.38,24.16c-16.39,38.51-9.6,73.02,16.57,103.79
                c24.74,29.1,56.59,39.85,93.94,28.93c13.32-3.9,22.43-2.53,32.47,8.62c28.52,31.65,58.14,62.37,88.33,92.45
                c12.93,12.89,22.9,23.79,11.38,43.35c-4.23,7.19-3.45,18.23-2.67,27.31c3.48,40.29,26.73,67.16,61.91,83.45
                c37.38,17.31,72.37,10.6,103.88-16.98c24.71,13,48.89,26.75,73.95,38.62c23.82,11.28,33.86,28.49,37,54.98
                c5.81,49.08,29.32,69.44,80.77,77.46c45.76,7.13,84.95-12.4,105.27-50.91c3.13-5.95,11.85-12.45,18.14-12.61
                c27.06-0.69,54.19,0.6,81.25,1.92c5.36,0.26,13.9,2.5,15.32,6.08c4.53,11.41,11.02,20.43,18.28,28.52l272.53-156.75l0.06-36.61
                c-35.19,16.39-70.23,33.11-105.4,49.56c-17.73,8.29-50.19-10.89-51.54-31.44c2.97-62.93,6.01-127.1,9.02-191.28
                c5.33-113.69,10.63-227.37,15.97-341.06c5.78-122.95,11.46-245.9,17.51-368.83c0.98-19.85,15.11-28.26,31.14-16.12
                c28.96,21.92,55.88,46.61,82.67,71.21c1.33,1.22,1.8,3.59,1.98,6.25l0.14-86.35c-12.75-11.24-25.89-22.06-38.17-33.79
                c-5.31-5.07-9.09-15.98-7.75-23.09c8.64-45.63-4.33-83.31-38.51-106.24c-37.01-24.83-77.3-26.83-114.18,2.81
                c-25.43,20.43-47.85,17.59-74.23,8.84c-13.12-4.35-19.86-11.14-22.89-25.37c-9.12-42.89-45.46-75.54-84.4-78.27
                c-48.06-3.36-93.26,19.29-105.51,62.78c-9.36,33.23-28.75,44.93-57.77,50.89c-6.8,1.4-13.89,2.84-19.98,5.96
                c-14.02,7.18-22.97,3.28-33.97-7.91c-30.51-31.06-82.55-36.2-123-14.55c-40.77,21.82-58.9,60.9-51.51,107.11
                c1.12,7.03-2.91,18.22-8.42,22.45c-36.24,27.82-73.8,53.91-110.34,81.36c-12.35,9.27-22.07,10.6-37.29,3.87
                c-69.23-30.6-157.63,28.66-144.36,99.9c6.67,35.83-6.25,53.38-28.88,72.8c-17.04,14.62-32.71,30.84-49.34,45.96
                c-5.96,5.43-12.93,9.75-21.06,15.78c-21.76-54.52-61.21-71.66-114.49-63.66c-5.36,0.8-13.55-2.95-17.22-7.3
                c-36.98-43.84-73.57-88.02-109.39-132.81c-4.24-5.31-6.5-16.22-4.04-22.22c16.69-40.51,9.22-76.58-20.14-107.15
                c-29.38-30.59-65.39-35.1-104.83-20.43c-5.77,2.14-15.62,1-20.26-2.74c-31.38-25.3-61.74-51.86-92.71-77.67
                c-9.78-8.15-12.65-15.93-10.17-29.83c10.29-57.8-29.42-109.39-86.89-115.11c-10.75-1.07-20.49,0.66-29.86,3.4 M1779.41,1291.33
                c-4.13,33.02-6.63,66.27-11.99,99.07c-1.4,8.58-9.08,20.05-16.69,23.06c-47.11,18.63-68.76,53.4-67.93,102.56
                c0.23,13.76-4.37,20.67-15.75,27.07c-29.66,16.66-58.48,34.81-87.9,51.9c-15.5,9-36.21-2.66-36.38-17.67
                c6.9-71.5,13.25-140.83,20.34-210.08c21.2-206.98,42.71-413.92,64.05-620.88c1.03-9.98,1.32-20.04,2.41-30.02
                c2.4-22.1,26.17-32.7,43.65-18.68c33.27,26.67,66.09,53.92,98.38,81.76c3.78,3.26,5.18,12.16,4.08,17.74
                c-8.68,44.25,6.47,78.45,40.6,106.68c5.97,4.94,9.27,17.45,8.27,25.81C1810.04,1050.26,1794.49,1170.76,1779.41,1291.33z
                 M2022.39,1079.74c-5.65,19.23-2.95,40.81-4.74,61.3c-0.87,10.01-0.91,21.93-6.31,29.38c-21.67,29.94-32.32,60.97-21.25,98.03
                c1.9,6.37-1.68,17.7-6.75,22.31c-47.61,43.17-96.09,85.39-144.41,127.77c-0.85,0.75-2.96,0.07-12.29-0.02
                c17.57-169.82,39.84-337.62,63.28-510.26c10.51,6.56,18.81,9.36,23.58,15.1c34.67,41.67,68.44,84.08,102.96,125.88
                C2024.43,1058.86,2026.4,1066.1,2022.39,1079.74z M2351.26,1113.5c-6.53,63.75-13.12,127.5-19.81,191.23
                c-0.64,6.1-1.44,12.35-3.4,18.11c-4.44,13.07-11.28,16.42-20.83,3.81c-35.44-46.8-70.93-93.57-109.47-144.41
                c52.22-48.8,103.22-96.46,154.22-144.12c2.11,1.08,4.21,2.16,6.32,3.23C2355.95,1065.4,2353.72,1089.46,2351.26,1113.5z
                 M2579.48,1564.84c-1.01,9.27-5.94,19.24-12.05,26.27c-2.3,2.65-15.49,0.27-19.73-3.88c-36.52-35.8-72.3-72.36-107.71-109.26
                c-3.21-3.34-4.43-11.19-3.06-15.95c14-48.79,0.31-87.86-38.77-119.6c-5.2-4.22-8.85-14.38-8.12-21.25
                c9.09-86.14,18.74-172.22,29.6-258.15c0.9-7.14,10.41-15.8,17.95-19.05c37.62-16.19,63.46-41.33,67.58-83.72
                c1.01-10.35-2.03-21.09-3.21-31.65c-1.34-0.48-2.67-0.95-4.01-1.42c3.9-6.96,6.14-16.12,11.97-20.52
                c41.38-31.26,83.38-61.69,125.6-91.8c2.99-2.13,11.78-1.31,13.64,1.23c3.93,5.37,7.5,13.01,6.95,19.35
                c-4.26,49.29-9.34,98.51-14.54,147.7C2621.08,1177.06,2600.56,1370.98,2579.48,1564.84z M2872.97,1471.1
                c-6.71,78.41-11.7,156.96-18.53,235.35c-0.96,10.99-5.83,28.79-12.61,30.79c-21.56,6.34-40.22,35.84-68.45,8.31
                c-14.24-13.9-36.59-19.45-55.2-28.91c-14.46-7.35-27.52-15.73-22.02-34.24c-2.57-33.39-17.02-59.29-42.58-78.03
                c-11.73-8.6-14.31-17.01-12.76-31.2c26.02-239.04,51.42-478.15,76.62-717.28c1.78-16.9,4.83-28.8,24.05-36.09
                c33.2-12.6,53.24-39.53,60.32-74.43c2.63-12.98,7.11-20.73,20.91-23.06c9.81-1.66,19.83-4.77,28.59-9.43
                c31.82-16.94,56.31-4.52,77.23,19.15c4.76,5.39,6.85,15.42,6.21,22.97C2914.42,993.72,2893.4,1232.39,2872.97,1471.1z
                 M3177.72,1131.36c-4.53,93.53-8.89,187.07-13.6,280.6c-5.02,99.68-10.47,199.33-15.47,299.01
                c-0.67,13.26-6.43,20.76-17.29,29.25c-19.03,14.86-34.29,34.48-51.78,51.43c-4.65,4.51-11.42,8.7-17.61,9.37
                c-13.01,1.4-26.5-1.13-39.42,0.64c-31.02,4.23-59.87,5.6-72.96-31.34c-0.95-2.68-3.65-5.78-6.24-6.69
                c-36.35-12.79-30.1-40.55-27.49-69.84c27.67-311.26,54.38-622.61,81.39-933.93c0.4-4.61-0.43-11.43,2.18-13.39
                c19.62-14.74,39.02-30.31,60.57-41.68c8.33-4.4,22.15,0.77,33.29,2.68c21.82,3.76,36.07,11.33,43.46,37.65
                c5.95,21.2,29.3,37.57,45.1,55.94c4.42,5.13,9.46,9.72,11.33,11.63C3187.85,922.66,3182.78,1027.01,3177.72,1131.36z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <circle cx="1608.14" cy="606.81" r="97.49"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <circle cx="1501.18" cy="1681.26" r="110.19"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <circle cx="3172.09" cy="1834.67" r="101.34"/>
        </g>
        <circle cx="3407.08" cy="1707.72" r="101.34"/>
        <circle cx="3408.44" cy="888.29" r="101.34"/>
    </g>
  
    <text transform="matrix(1.0665 0 0 1 3229.4033 1631.7931)" ><tspan class="st3 st4 st5"> </tspan><tspan class="st3 st4 st5 st6">B</tspan><tspan class="st3 st4 st5 st7">I</tspan><tspan  class="st3 st4 st5 st8">OTECH GRO</tspan><tspan class="st3 st4 st5 st6">UP</tspan></text>
    <path class="st3" d="M424.08,546.76h196.26v1168.82H480.15V890.21l-136.69,825.36h-70.09L136.69,890.21v825.36H0V546.76h192.76
        l115.66,581.78L424.08,546.76z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M909.2,1715.58H746.23V546.76H909.2V1715.58z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M1126.61,699.21H974.15V546.76h474.89v152.45h-159.47v1016.37h-162.97V699.21z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```